# Multi-pane scrolling via CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a dual pane view, where the top banner of the screen is fixed, while the bottom can scroll horizontally. As the user scrolls horizontally, they should still be able to see the same top banner. I've attached some sample code and a corresponding [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgoklani/d70trj60/2/).

The problem is that as the user scrolls past GROUP2 to GROUP3, the top header gets cropped. I would like the header to continue across the top of the screen as the user scrolls.

```
<div>
  <div class="header">
    COMPANY NAME
  </div>
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="group1">
      GROUP1
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
      GROUP2
    </div>
    <div class="group3">
      GROUP3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



.header {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background:red;
}
.scroller {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
.group1 {
  top:80px;
  left:0px;
  width:500px;
  position:absolute;
}
.group2 {
  top:80px;
  left:540px;
  width:500px;
  position:absolute;
}
.group3 {
  top:80px;
  left:1080px;
  width:500px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d70trj60/6/)

```
.header {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background:red;
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```